# Will managed C++ (CLI) code ported from C# work faster than original C#? ( tcp server)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, performance, translation

So we created simple C# tcp sever for video sharing. all it does is simple and shall be done "life" - recive live video packed into container (FLV in our case) from some broadcaster and share recived stream with all subscribers (means open container  and create new containers and make timestamps on container structure but not decode contents of packets in any way). We tested our server but found out that its performance is not enough for 5 incoming streamers and 10 outgoing streams. Fe found [this app](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html?gclid=CPy9u7vbkacCFcRG3gods0sfdg) for porting. We will try it any way but before we try I wonder if any of you have tried such thing on any of your projects. So main question - is will C++ CLI make app faster than original C#?

Comment: I suspect you can write good and bad code in either... it is hard to say, without reviewing the C#, whether another approach might just be "fix some suboptimal C#"...

Comment: Have you profiled your code to find out where the cycles are being spent? The # of clients you can support seems on the lowish side, but w/o knowing where the squeeze points are, you're guessing.

Comment: I can guarantee you that a program that converts C# to C++ will not perform as well as a program that was just converted by hand into C++.  It sound like either the code itself is the problem or the hardware is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Writing the same code in a different language won't make any difference whatsoever; it will still compile to the same IL.

C# is not a slow language; you probably have some higher-level performance issues.
You should optimize your existing code.

Answer (score 2):

**Not for most code**, however if the code does a lot of **bit level operations** maybe.   Likewise if you can safely make use of **unmanaged memory** to reuse the load on the garbage collector.

So **just** doing a translation of the code to managed C++ is very unlikely to have a benefit for most code, however  managed C++ may let you write some code in a more complex, (and unsafe) way that runs faster.

Comment: Bit-level operations are no faster in C++/CLI than in C# - it's the same IL.

Comment: @SLaks you are assuming only managed C++ without the use of any unmanaged C/C++, mixing the two is where managed C++ comes into it's own.

Comment: That is true, but you won't get that from an automated converter.

Answer (score 1):

No- not at all. C++/CLI runs on the same .NET platform as C#, effectively preventing any speed increase purely by changing language. Native C++ on the other hand may yield *some* benefits, but it's best to be very careful. You're most likely to yield performance benefits from a profiler than changing language, and you should only consider changing language after extensive testing of the language and code that you have.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling some functions from a native DLL via P/Invoke approach, then at least converting those callback mechanisms to C++/Cli using IJW (It Just Works) would increase the performance a bit.